# Topics and Questions I can ask about here! (Can you give us your feedback?)

Tags: discussion, questions

@FFrewin has suggested that we improve the [What topics can I ask about here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) wiki page as there is very little information on it.

I know for sure that everyone will have different opinions on what types of questions are suitable for JSE, so it would be great to get everyone's feedback below so we can come to a final consensus and write some information on that page.

Here are some meta questions that have been asked in the past for reference:

- [Are questions about configuring 3rd party Joomla extensions 'on-topic'?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305/168)
- ["Please fix my code" kind of questions](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/168)
- [Are extension recommendations on topic?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/168)

Answer (score 5):

## Current Site Scope

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).

---

### Main On-Topic Questions:

- Installation, Administration & Configuration
- Templates & Extensions Development
- Using Joomla API
- Integrations between Joomla and other Platforms - pertaining to the Joomla side of things.
- Development and Administration Best Practices
- Server Configuration for Joomla

<sub>[TO-DO] Link to meta Topic with Examples of Good and Bad Questions for each category.</sub>

---

#### Questions about 3rd party Extensions, Templates, Hosting:

Questions asking for extensions recommendations or support may be, or may not be considered on-topic, It depends on the overall context of the question and how it is being asked. Please read the following discussions in our Meta site for more information:

- Recommendations - read:  [Are extension recommendations on topic?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/are-extension-recommendations-on-topic)
- Support - read: [Are questions about configuring 3rd party Joomla extensions 'on-topic'?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/are-questions-about-configuring-3rd-party-joomla-extensions-on-topic)

> Definitely, if you need support for 3rd party extensions, you should
>   make sure you have first read the documentation, then also exhaust the
>   support channels that are available from the extensions' developers.

---

### Off-topic:

In most cases, the following type of questions will be considered as Off-Topic.

#### Not Directly Specific to Joomla:

- Generic PHP/MySQL/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery/TinyMCE issues and development (even if Joomla is based on these technologies)- try [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Generic SEO - you may be luckier at [WebmastersSE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- Generic Security or writing Secure Code - try [SecuritySE](https://security.stackexchange.com) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Generic server configuration and administration - try [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)
- Hosting issues - Contact your hosting provider.

#### Too Localized, Work-for-me-for-free, require Professional Hands-on involvement, or Reporting Bugs or Security Vulnerabilities:

- Reporting and requesting a fix for Joomla Security Vulnerabilities or Bugs. If it's older Joomla version - update immediately. If it's the latest Joomla Version, then use [**Joomla.org**](https://developer.joomla.org/security.html) and report there what you have found.
- Fixing syntax errors, ask to work on code with restricted access, or on a problem that can not be replicated.
- Overly complex or specific things.
- Recovering from hacks and server issues -unless you are encountering a specific issue that falls under the on-topic categories.
- Pasting some demo or tutorial code and asking to refactor it to a final workable solution to meet your specific requirements.
- Always when asking for coding help, you must present your efforts and that you are somewhat up to the task. Questions that just contain requirements and ask us to code a solution are off-topic.
- If your question fits in the context of the above 4 items, our best advice is to hire an expert to work for you, instead of asking for free work.

<sub>[TO-DO] Link to meta Topic with Examples of "Fix-my-code/Work for free" questions.</sub>

---

### Recommended Reading on how to ask for help:

- http://xyproblem.info
- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

---

If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

---

### Related Discussions:

- **[How to judge a new question: flagging, vote to close, editing?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-judge-a-new-question-flagging-vote-to-close-editing?noredirect=1&lq=1)**

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by [Joomla 4.0 does not save the article with Joomla fields](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24519/12352) which is (at the time of this post) On Hold for being:

> **Off-topic**: "Questions must be specific to Joomla. Generic questions about web, programming, 3rd party software, servers, hosting etc, even if they are found in the Joomla-sphere, are off-topic. It might be better asked at Stack Overflow or another SE Site. For Joomla Extension Support better use their developers' support channels first. More info: help center"

This is a question that seems to point to a potential bug in the not yet released Joomla 4.

If the most appropriate place to post this issue is on GitHub, I think this guidance should be clearly stipulated in the Help Center and either a new close justification be created or an existing Off-topic justification should me appended with this reason.

Ultimately, we don't want JSE to be an extension of Joomla.org/GitHub's issue reporting process.  We don't want Joomla core developers to have to comb the questions here for issues there.

I guess a minor adjustment would be to rephrase as:

> If it's the latest or a not-yet-released Joomla version, then use Joomla.org and report there what you have found.  *...or GitHub?*

and the message displayed on the closed page should reflect this condition.

---

A few more things...

1. > Overly complex or specific things.

   This seems like it is very subjective and potentially unfair.

   - If a question is overly complex, but sufficient details have been provided so that the question is not Too Broad, then we shouldn't deflect "tricky" questions.
   - If a something is very specific, and the question provides sufficient details to make the issue reproducible, then it should be fair game.
2. > Generic PHP/MySQL/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery/TinyMCE issues and development (even if Joomla is based on these technologies)

   I don't see a lot of questions being closed for this reason and I think this is a good thing.  It will only encourage more growth in the community if there aren't too many rigid restrictions on Joomla-associated questions.  Furthermore, since we want Joomla users to search for Joomla-related issues here, I think it is a good idea to grant some lenience on this point so that researchers have a better chance of finding a solution here.