# How to judge a new question: flagging, vote to close, editing?

Tags: discussion

We have recently updated our **[help/on-topic](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** page.
There is an open discussion also here:
**[Topics and Questions I can ask about here! (Can you give us your feedback?)](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/topics-and-questions-i-can-ask-about-here-can-you-give-us-your-feedback)**.  Anyone that has something to suggest is free to join that discussion.

As most if you should already know, SE sites are mostly run by the community and their members. Actually, the majority of the moderation needed occurs by the members. The moderators are here to generally supervise that the rules are obeyed and to provide any solutions when there is a need. 
But still, the good standing and health of this site, remains a responsibility of the whole community - each member new or old contributes (or at least he should) to that.

Now, that we have a definition on what On/Off-Topic questions are, it would be also useful to ensure that everyone has a good understanding on how to judge a new question, when to flag it, when to vote for closing, what reason to use to justify the close vote, and so on.

Are there any advises on how to review new questions? 
When to vote a question for closing, how to use the correct close reason, or when to flag a question for moderation?

Answer (score 6):

Searching in the StackExchange network, I came across this Meta Discussion: **[Close reasons cheat sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215587/close-reasons-cheat-sheet)**.

I found a simple flow chart, that can act as a brief and easy to follow manual. I slightly modified for our Joomla SE site and am posting it here:

[image: moderating question flow chart]

> #### General note:
>
> Flagging posts to request Moderators involvement should
>   be used sparingly, and when there are serious problems with a question
>   (or answer). There are plenty of tools, for the community itself to judge and
>   moderate Questions or Answers. Technical inaccuracies in posts,
>   or technically wrong answers do not require a moderator to do
>   anything. You can simply vote down. 
>   **Read more: [What are acceptable reasons for flagging as "Requires Moderator attention"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/what-are-acceptable-reasons-for-flagging-as-requires-moderator-attention)**

Comment: Further information about flagging and with guideline links:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Thanks for adding this link here @DennisHeiden

Comment: Not only "has it been answered here before" but "has it been asked here before", right? Do you want to see redundant questions? If so, do you want new attention to the new question and if/when it is answered, you would like to see the earlier question closed as a duplicate of the new one?  My original thought: even if an old question is not answered, the new one is still a duplicate question right?  Of course, if the new question is slightly different, explain the difference in the new question and link to the similar/pre-existing question.